# How to turn a jade page into html?

Tags: html, node.js, express, pug

I have a jade file called syntax.jade. What I need is a way to convert syntax.jade, along with the information I would normally pass it with a res.render statement, into a html document in node so that I can manipulate it in that form. Basically what I want is this:

when I use

```
res.render('syntax', {comment: comment}, function(err, html))
```

html contains the html of the page as a string. I need another way to get that code that doesn't require me to render the page in the browser.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can include the resulting HTML code in another res.render statement in order to provide formatting instead of doing all the formatting in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is already what you have. From the express docs on `res.render`

> When a callback is provided both the possible error and rendered
>   string are passed, and no automated response is performed.

So `res.render(viewName, locals)` does BOTH rendering of the HTML and sending that HTML as the HTTP response body. However `res.render(viewName, locals, callback)` with 3 arguments just renders the HTML and passes it to the callback without sending any HTTP response. Thus you can do whatever is needed with the HTML and then send a response later.

There is also `app.render` which is another general utility to render stuff without having anything to do with a particular http request/response.

Answer (score 1):

You can just require Jade as a Node module and use the `renderFile()` method.

```
var jade = require('jade');

jade.renderFile('syntax.jade', {comment: comment}), function (err, html) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // rendered string is in html variable
});
```

If there's no error, then you have a rendered HTML string as a result. If you want to do this synchronously, then just don't specify a callback:

```
var html = jade.renderFile('filename.jade', {comment: comment});
```